# Transform to cylindrical coordinate system

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, vector-analysis, coordinate-systems

I tried so many approaches ,  at least give me a hint on how to find 
The ***unit vectors*** 
$$ \vec{V} = y\vec{i} + x\vec{j} + \frac{x^2}{\sqrt[2]{x^2+y^2})} \vec{k}\ $$
[image]

Comment: Should I Search for vector units using The jacobian matrice or, I just start with the x, y

Comment: Do you want to find the unit vector in the direction of $V$? You need to find the norm of $V$, which is $\sqrt{\frac{(x^2+y^2)^2+x^4}{x^2+y^2}}$, then divide $V$ by its norm. And what does your title mean?

Comment: I presume you are asking for an explanation of transforming from Cartesian to cylindrical co-ordinates?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system

Comment: Exactly thank yu Thank you , apreciat it